# How to cascade specific fields of the object or array to the existing object or array. (JS and React)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, lodash

I'm trying to...

1. get the specific field of data from the object in the object
2. **set the states with the obtained data at once (if it's possible)**

Here is `taggedItems` which I want to edit (setState).

```
taggedItems = {
  0: { id: 0, width: 40, height: 40, image: null, base64: null },
  1: { id: 1, width: 200, height: 200, image: null, base64: null },
  2: { id: 2, width: 80, height: 80, image: null, base64: null }
}
```

I'm cropping the `taggedItems` from the image. I'm getting `image` and `base64` data.

```
for (var key in taggedItems) {
    ..
    // Get successURI, base64 value
    // Store it to array or object (Can store them in array, object or any type. 
    // Because I don't prefer to setState in the for-loop.
    // exampleArray = [
    //   { id: 0, image: 'file:path1', base64: 'ksdnflksdf' },
    //   { id: 1, image: 'file:path2', base64: 'fldmlkflkj' },
    //   { id:2, image: 'file:path3', base64: 'glkmdlfg' },
    // ]

// HERE IS THE PROBLEM: I want to setState all of items at once(if it's possible) 
setState({taggedItems: ???});
```

Expected output of `this.state.taggedItems` after `setState` right above will be

```
taggedItems = {
   0: { id: 0, width: 40, height: 40, image: 'file:path1', base64: 'ksdnflksdf' },
   1: { id: 1, width: 200, height: 200, image: 'file:path2', base64: 'fldmlkflkj' },
   2: { id: 2, width: 80, height: 80, image: 'file:path3', base64: 'glkmdlfg' }
}
```

I will convert object into array anyway to send the data into the JSON so please feel free to use any type of variable (Array or Object).

Comment: Guys! Please feel free to help me to edit for improving my question :) I appreciate that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure if I'm understanding correctly, but it sounds like you just want to merge the objects inside two arrays. If that's the case you can do it pretty easily with `.map` and the spread operator:

```js
const taggedItems = [
  {id:0, width:40, height:40, image:null, base64:null},
  {id:1, width:200, height:200, image:null, base64:null},
  {id:2, width:80, height:80, image:null, base64:null}
];

const exampleArray = [
  {id:0, image: 'file:path1', base64: 'ksdnflksdf'},
  {id:1, image: 'file:path2', base64: 'fldmlkflkj'},
  {id:2, image: 'file:path3', base64: 'glkmdlfg'},
];

const merged = taggedItems.map((tagged, i) => {
  return {
    ...tagged,
    ...exampleArray[i]
  };
});

console.log(merged);
```

### More info

[More info about object spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator) and some comments that might help explain:

```
const merged = taggedItems.map((tagged, i) => {
  // for every item in `taggedItems` return a new object
  return {
    // take all properties from `tagged`
    ...tagged,
    // get all properties from `exampleArray[i]`
    ...exampleArray[i]
  };
  // The new object will contain all properties from `tagged` + `exampleArray[i]` in that order.
  // If there are duplicated the latter one will overwrite.
});
```

Comment: THIS IS EXACTLY WHAT I WAS LOOKING FOR

Comment: And could explain a little bit about how it's working??? It works like a magic. Thanks

Comment: @JohnBaek glad i could help! I added some comments that I hope makes it more clear

Comment: @AustinGreco this is great , i learned something new , just to add one more point the order inside `return` is important(you have mentioned that) otherwise the later one will override properties of first one